# OAuth access token request failing (NSErrorFailingURLStringKey)

Tags: iphone, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, nsurlerrordomain

I have the following steps completed in the OAuth process:
1) Request token
2) Authorize token
3) Receive PIN number

What I can't get to work is getting the access token with the PIN I receive.  It always hits my `accessTokenTicket:didFailWithError` selector.

Here's the URL that's getting passed to it:
http://www.formspring.me/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=TOKEN_KEY_HERE&oauth_verifier=PIN_HERE

And here's the code that's being called:

```
- (void)successfulAuthorizationWithPin:(NSString *)pin {
    NSLog(@"successfulAuthorizationWithPin:%@", pin);<br>
    OAMutableURLRequest *request;<br>
    OADataFetcher *fetcher;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kOAuthAccessTokenURL];

    request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                               consumer:self.consumer
                                                  token:self.accessToken
                                                  realm:nil
                                      signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];

    OARequestParameter *p0 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_token" value:self.accessToken.key];
    OARequestParameter *p1 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier"
                                                                value:pin];

    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p0, p1, nil];
    [request setParameters:params];
    [request prepare];

    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);

    fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];

    [p0 release];
    [p1 release];
}
```

And the `didFail` method (just an `NSLog` of the error) produces this error:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x6160c20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.formspring.me/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=TOKEN_KEY_HERE&oauth_verifier=PIN_HERE, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.formspring.me/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=TOKEN_KEY_HERE&oauth_verifier=PIN_HERE, NSUnderlyingError=0x61321f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}`

Am I formatting the URL wrong or supplying wrong or not enough parameters?

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 3):

Did you check if the oauth token generated was correct? I would suggest starting there. [Here's](http://developer.netflix.com/resources/OAuthtest) a good resource to check your OAuth tokens.

The message comes up if there is an authentication error. Generate the URL via the Netflix Oauth verification and run it on a browser. See if it loads then.